# modifying three if statements in bash, possibly with regular expression?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that checks if the input message is in the following format.
"category: explanation".
and it will return success only if categories are one of bash, java, python.
Bash isn't my language so pardon me for this ugly looking code.

```
#!/bin/sh
input=$1
if[["$input"==bash:*]]
then exit 0
fi 
if[["$input"==java:*]]
then exit 0
fi 
if[["$input"==python:*]]
then exit 0
fi 
echo "categories are python, bash, java. and must use category:whatever explanation format" 
exit 1
```

this is obviously very bad.
but my logic is simple, if the input doesn't start with the category(bash, java, python):
then it reaches the end of the script and return 1:error message
How do I modify this script?

Edit: I thought about maybe there's a better way to check if category: exists in the argument.
maybe I can do
input=`grep -i 'bash:' $1`
input2=`grep -i 'python:' $1`
input3=`grep -i 'java:' $1`

```
if ["{$input} && {$input2} &&{$input3}"];
then echo "respect the format" 
exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: The code which you posted is not just ugly, it is simply syntactically incorrect. If you want to ask for improving a piece of code, make sure at least that it at least runs. Also, it is not written for bash, but has a #! line for sh. Please make up your mind first whether you want to discuss a POSIX shell script or a bash script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a good use-case for a `case` switch:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

input=$1

# Exctract category name by stripping trailing :*
category=${input%%:*}

if ! {
  # category and input differs in length if it starts with name:
  [ ${#category} -ne ${#input} ] &&
  case "$category" in
    bash | java | python) ;;
    *) false;;
  esac
} then
  echo "categories are python, bash, java. and must use category:whatever explanation format"
  exit 1
fi
```

Using a function to clarify code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

format_ok() {
  category="${1%%:*}"
  [ "$category" != "$1" ] \
    && case "$category" in
      bash | java | python) ;;
      *) false ;;
    esac
}

input=$1

if ! format_ok "$input"; then
  echo "categories are python, bash, java. and must use category:whatever explanation format"
  exit 1
fi
```

Now with Bash Regex, this is probably even simpler:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! [[ $1 =~ (bash|java|python): ]]; then
  echo "categories are python, bash, java. and must use category:whatever explanation format"
  exit 1
fi
```

Or using Bash extended globbing patterns:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob # Enable extended globbing patterns

if [[ $1 != @(bash|java|python): ]]; then
  echo "categories are python, bash, java. and must use category:whatever explanation format"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm little bit confused. so this line, category=${1%%:*} extracts "category:" and case switch checks if it's bash:|java:|python: ?

Comment: @clarkemily `category=${input%%:*}` removes the colon and anything after from `$input`.

Comment: Hi do you know how to use this script file as git hook pre-receive file?